# Failed connection to PostgreSql

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to connect in C# to my PostgreSQL db but I keep getting the same error:

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
> ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.data. (C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\Licenta\Dubla 1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp1.dll.config line 26)

Here is my `app.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.3" newVersion="4.1.1.3" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add
          name="PostgreSQLDB"
          connectionString="host=localhost;port=5432;database=dcae;user id=fff;password=fff;"
          providerName="Npgsql" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
            <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    

    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry within `<configSections>` for `<system.data>`

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.data" type="...[fill in your type]"/>
  </configSections>
```

Comment: What is type meaning? I do not understand the type of what shoud be